# Student's T Distributions in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, distribution

Currently I've written a function in Excel VBA that basically uses a table of data to calculate a Z score. I then get a probability value from this Z score by using the excel function NormSDist. The last few lines of the code look like this:

```
...

Dim disToDef As Double: disToDef = (Log(asset(iNumRows) / debt(iNumRows)) + (meanAsset - sigmaAsset ^ 2 / 2) * maturity) / (sigmaAsset * Sqr(maturity))
Dim defProb As Double: defProb = WorksheetFunction.NormSDist(-disToDef)

KMVModel = defProb

End Function
```

I want to get a function equivalent to NormSDist(z) for the T distribution, where I can leave z as a variable. I don't think one exists in Excel - what would be a good way to approach this?

Comment: If NormSDist works (does it work?), what exactly do you want?

Comment: NormSDist works, but instead of using the normal distribution, I want to use the student's T distribution.

Comment: Student's ... is that a standard name for a well known distribution?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that's a [standard name for a well-know distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel can handle the T distribution:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.T_Dist(0.95, 20, False) 'pdf value
    Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.T_Dist(0.95, 20, True) 'cdf value
End Sub
```

Output:

```
0.247866113626846 
0.823274027108808
```

Comment: Glad it worked. I should also point out that the inverse of the T-dist is also built-in, which is useful for finding critical values for hypothesis testing.